# Implementing tcp's accept() function

Tags: python, tcp, implementation

As a part of a school assignment we are required to implement a very simple version of tcp in `python`. Communication it self is done over a `udp` socket.

My problem is with the implementaion of `accept()`, mainly supporting multiple clients. I read alot about it, but couldn't find any source to answer my questions. Here's my code right now:

```
# Accepts an incoming connection. This method blocks until an incoming SYN message
# arrives, handles the SYN message and returns the socket.
def accept(self):
    if self.state < STCP_STATE_LISTEN:
        raise StcpSocketException("Socket not listening")

    # Extract syn segment
    while True:
        syn = stcp_packet.read_from_socket(self.sock)
        if syn.syn:
            log.debug("(%s,%s) received SYN %s" % (self.local_addr, self.local_port, syn))
            break

    # TODO allocates the TCP buffers and variables

    # Allocate new socket
    connection = stcp_socket()
    connection.bind(self.local_addr, 0)
    connection.remote_addr = syn.srcIp
    connection.remote_port = syn.srcPort
    connection.change_state(STCP_STATE_SYN_RCVD)

    # Send syn ack segment
    syn_ack = connection.create_empty_pkt(True, True, False, None, syn.seqNum + 1)
    self.seqNum += 1
    connection.sock.sendto(syn_ack.pack(), syn.srcIp, syn.srcPort)
    log.debug("(%s,%s) sent SYN ACK %s" % (connection.local_addr, connection.local_port, syn_ack))

    # Extract last segment in handshake process
    while True:
        ack = stcp_packet.read_from_socket(connection.sock)
        if ack.ack:
            log.debug("(%s,%s) received ACK %s" % (connection.local_addr, connection.local_port, ack))
            connection.change_state(STCP_STATE_ESTAB)
            break

    return connection
```

And my questions:

1. Should the new socket respond to the syn packet, or should the old (listener) socket finish the 3-way handshake?
2. Should the client keep sending packets to the listening socket, which in turn will pass the to the newly created socket, or should the client obtain the new socket's IP and port from the syn_ack packet and send packets directly?

Comment: Read [accept(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html) man page.

Answer (score 0):

> Should the new socket respond to the syn packet, or should the old (listener) socket finish the 3-way handshake?

The old one should if ha the handshake. The peer should be expecting the entire handshake sequence to come from the same IP:port.

> Should the client keep sending packets to the listening socket, which in turn will pass the to the newly created socket

No.

> or should the client obtain the new socket's IP and port from the syn_ack packet and send packets directly?

Yes. The final ACK will need to contain the new port number.